# straddle return

Tags: options, black-scholes

I have the following options data. This is just a snippet but this data is available every day  Period 30 to 720 and Out of the Money : 0 to 60 in increments of 5
I would like to compute short straddle return for each day. Its been a while since I used options and was wondering if someone could guide me

```
    ID  Symbol  TradeDate Period Strike_Price     Call_Put  Out_of_the_Money    IV  Delta
    2631442 A   17-Jul-17   30  12591.56            P        0             0.10793-0.49383
    2631443 A   17-Jul-17   30  12591.56            C        0             0.10738 0.50614
    2629567 A   14-Jul-17   30  12616.31            P        0             0.10864-0.49379
    2629568 A   14-Jul-17   30  12616.31            C        0             0.1074  0.50614
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, to calculate returns you need prices, which I don't see in your data. Second, while long options positions are trivial to calculate, short positions and spreads require margin deposit that depends on the product you trade, and your broker's risk policy.